# Dual Monitor Black Screen after Login

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have two monitors connected to my Intel IGPU (Graphics 630
) on 18.04.3 LTS

They worked fine during setup, they also work fine on Desktop but when I log in, one of them always stays black. It is actually on and not turned off but simply displays black.

I can fix this by opening display settings on one monitor, resetting the displays to mirroring and then setting them back to dual display config. Everything works fine until I log out and log in again.

What is the best way to diagnose this? Is there any configuration I can examine? The xrandr output looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've sorted this out yet but I had a similar problem [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021737/ubuntu-16-04-second-monitor-goes-black-after-login) worked for me. 
Specifically, going into  Software & Updates -> Additional drivers and selecting Nvidia proprietary fixed the problem.